# Static and Interface class members

Tags: interface, static-classes

When we declare a class as static, we need to explicitly declare each member as Static, otherwise compiler error.
But, When we declare an interface, we do not need to declare all members as public, they are public by-default.
Any idea why such behavior?

Comment: can you declare a class as static or are you referring to inner class as static?

Comment: I am in reference of C#
like public static class Customer {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**public**, **protected**, **internal**, **protected internal**, and **private**, are all [access modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/access-modifiers). Every type in C# has a default accessibility level, so you needn't explicitly define them.

The **static** keyword is a modifier, but it is not an *access modifier*. Most modifiers require explicit declaration.

As to why they made it compulsory to define your members in a static class as **static**, I'm not certain. It could be because static classes can contain non-static (i.e. instantiable) nested types; it might cause problems if those were being declared as static by default.